# What is the solution to this parametric equation problem?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

How can I find the parametric equations of the line passing through the point $(-5,7,-2)$ and perpendicular to both the vectors $(2,1,-3)$ and $(5,4,-1)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the parametric equation for a line when a point on it and its direction vector is given, then a hint for finding the direction is trying to find $(2,1,-3)\times (5,4,-1)$, for the cross product produces a vector perpendicular to both these two vectors.

Answer (score 1):

Solution should be $x(t)=-5+at$, $y(t)=7+bt$, $z(t)=-2+ct$, where $(a,b,c)$ is a vector product of the vectors $(2,1,-3)$ and $(5,4,-1)$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\vec a = \left<2,1,-3\right>$ and $\vec b = \left<5,4,-1\right>$. Since we know the line is perpendicular to $\vec a$ and $\vec b$, we need a vector $\vec c$ that is perpendicular to $\vec a$ and $\vec b$ representing the direction of the line. This vector can be obtained by finding $\vec a \times \vec b$.

$$
\vec c = \left| \begin{array}{ccc} \hat i & \hat j & \hat k \\ 2 & 1 & -3 \\ 5 & 4 & -1 \end{array} \right|
$$

I'll assume you know how to find a cross product of two vectors and omit the computation. If you need help with that, here's a note on cross products: http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/CrossProduct.aspx.

$\vec a \times \vec b$ gives $\vec c = \left<11,-13,3\right>$. We know that a parametric representation of a line can be found as

$$
\vec r = \left<x_0,y_0,z_0\right> + \left<a,b,c\right>t
$$
Where $\left<x_0,y_0,z_0\right>$ represents a point on the line, $\vec r$, and $\left<a,b,c\right>$ represents its direction vector, $\vec c$ in our case.

Plugging everything in,

$$
\vec r = \left<-5,7,-2\right> + \left<11,-13,3\right>t
$$

$$
\vec r = \left<-5,7,-2\right> + \left<11t,-13t,3t\right>
$$

$$
\vec r = \left<11t-5,-13t+7,3t-2\right>
$$

Looking at $\vec r$ by component, we see that

$$
x(t) = 11t-5
$$

$$
y(t) = -13t+7
$$

$$
z(t) = 3t-2
$$